# Anyone used the Google Analytics plug-in for Google Sheets? Is it possible to schedule the data to run more frequently than once per hour?

Tags: google-analytics, google-sheets, google-docs, google-analytics-api

We have GA Premium and I am running about 50 reports in a Google Sheets using the Google Analytics plug-in.

I would like it to run once every 15 minutes or so. At least 30 minutes, however at the moment it's only allowing me to run once an hour.

Is it possible to write a script to run the add-on item "Run reports"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The native Google Analytics plug-in can only be run once per hour, however if you use Google Scripts to query the Google Analytics API (using JavaScript) - you can run it every minute if you want.

[image]